# How to elegantly connect many signals to a function in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt, signals, pyqt5, slot

I am currently building an interface using PyQt5 and I was wondering if there is an elegant way to connect several signals to the same function?

The straight-forward solution is this:

```
self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(self.Function)
self.ui.button2.clicked.connect(self.Function)
self.ui.button3.clicked.connect(self.Function)
self.ui.button4.clicked.connect(self.Function)
```

but is there a nicer, more readable option? For example something that would look like:

```
self.Function.connect(self.ui.button1.clicked,
                       self.ui.button2.clicked,
                       self.ui.button3.clicked,
                       self.ui.button4.clicked)
```

Also I started reading about `QSignalMapper`s but if they can be avoided it's nice.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function that takes a tuple or list of buttons as an argument, then connects the click signal for each one.

```
    self.connect_buttons((self.ui.button1, self.ui.button2, self.ui.button3, self.ui.button4))

def connect_buttons(self, button_tup):
    for button in button_tup:
        button.clicked.connect(self.Function)
```

Comment: Eliminate the tuple by using: `def connect_buttons(self, *buttons):`.